# iOS6 native facebook share dialog url

Tags: ios, facebook

I have used a native post dialog and I am passing an URL to the method that actually displays the dialog.The URL actually gets posted to the Facebook as needed.But I don't want this URL to be shown in post dialog, because if the user modifies it my mistake then some wrong text gets posted.Is there anyway hiding the URL in dialog. I am using the method presentShareDialogModallyFrom:initialText:image:url:handler: to present the native post dialog.

Comment: Are you passing the URL as a `NSURL`?

Comment: Yes it is an NSURL object.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't show any code so we don't know how you pass the URL. You probably use the `setInitialText:` method, whereas you need the `addURL:` method.

```
SLComposeViewController *facebookController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[facebookController setInitialText:self.titel];
[facebookController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.guid]];

[self presentViewController:facebookController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I am using the method + (BOOL)presentShareDialogModallyFrom:(UIViewController*)viewController
                          initialText:(NSString*)initialText
                                image:(UIImage*)image
                                  url:(NSURL*)url
                              handler:(FBShareDialogHandler)handler;
to present the native post dialog

Comment: You shouldn't. Use this one provided by Apple in iOS 6.

Comment: I used the same thing, but the url is still being displayed in the post dialog.

Answer (score -2):

Facebook native share, you have to implements `Accounts Framework` in to your app

In your framwork you have to Add: `Social.framework`

In your File .h add:

```
#import "Social/Social.h"

    @interface UIViewController {

    SLComposeViewController *FBCompose;

    }
```

In your file .m under a `IBAction` add:

```
- (IBAction)facebook:(id)sender {

    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"imageURL"]];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    //----here you can get pragmaticaly a part of yout text
    NSString *mutableArry = (self.myMutableDictionay)[@"string"];

    FBCompose = [[SLComposeViewController alloc]init];
    FBCompose = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [FBCompose setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ishare on FB %@  from MyApp App", mutableArry]];
    [FBCompose addImage:image];
    [FBCompose addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://Link of my app or get the link by myMutableDictionay"]];

    [self presentViewController:FBCompose animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Edit my post because is incomplete sorry.

Hope this help you ;)

Comment: What is FBCompose? This should be an object of SLComposeViewController. And what is that weird `mutableArry`?

Comment: is your SLComposeViewController in your .h file

Comment: Edited my post, sorry for incomplete code before and worg fro MutabalArray is a MutableDictionary (but this is optional you can get a strig where you want)

Comment: Still, some huge errors in this code. `mutableArry` has a horrible name and `(self.myMutableDictionary)[@"string"];` is wrong too. Also you should start the name of an object with a lower case character. `FBCompose` is simply wrong.

Comment: 1: There is no need to create an ivar for the composer. 2: Downloading an image this way will block the main thread and create poor UX. 3: Your instances should start with a lowercase letter, as is the convention. 4: There is no need to alloc/init the SLComposeViewController instance as `composeViewControllerForServiceType:` will handle this for you.

Comment: I used the same thing, but the url is still being displayed in the post dialog.

Comment: In a Facebook social box the URL is not possible to remove, in Twitter the URL is read like attachment and is hide for the User.